# Why can I boot Windows only with grub2 chainloader?

Tags: windows, grub2

When I updated my dual boot (Windows and Linux) PC my grub menu.lst file was deleted and I could no longer boot into Windows or Linux.

Finally I have succeeded in installing grub2 and I can boot both OSs but I cannot repair my Windows OS with the recovery console.

I've still some problems with grub2 and Windows 7 but I expected to repair it from the recovery console.

I assume the mbr of my Windows disk is ok because it works with the chainloader from grub2.

The problem is I cannot boot Windows without the chainloader or grub. It even failed to write a new boot sector because Windows cannot detect the filesystem. This happens to me with the bootrec.exe /FixBoot command. I also cannot command bootrec.exe /RepairBCD it gives the same error.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and explain exactly what isn't working?  You state you can boot both OSs, so what is the problem?  How does the title fit into the issue?

Comment: Pault: I can boot booth OS but I need grub2 to boot Windows? What if I doesn't want Linux anymore? What if my Linux get corrupted? I've tried to boot from my Windows to no avail? Btw. After an update of Linux this happens exactly to me.

Comment: Are you saying that you are testing Windows Recovery just in case something goes wrong?

Comment: Paul: I don't understand? I got problem to boot at all my OS. Now I'm wondering why I can't boot with Windows Recovery my PC and only with chainloader? Do this sound weird?

Comment: It is just unclear.  You have said that you can boot both OSs successfully, and you have said you have a problem booting all of your OSs.  These cannot both be correct.

Comment: Paul: I boot both OS but only with Grub and Grub Chainloader???? I want to boot my Windows with the Windows Bootloader only??? How is this complicated to understand?

Comment: It was difficult to understand because you have never stated in any of this dialog or the original question that you no longer want grub, and so no longer want to be able to boot your linux installation.  Please [edit] and rephrase the question: "I have grub installed and want to remove it and replace it with the standard windows 7 boot loader".

Comment: I don't want to remove grub. I want to know in case my next update of opensuse destroys the grub again so I've the option to boot into Windows. In my title I've asked exactly this?? Seriously what has this do with grub and my pc and how I boot my os?

Comment: Because you cannot have both the grub bootloader and the windows bootloader installed in the MBR simultaneously.  Installing the Windows bootloader will remove the grub bootloader.  I'll leave this question for someone else to help you with.

Comment: Can you run `chkdsk`? If so, what does it say the format is?

Comment: Paul: Sure I can. I have 2 hard disk. 1 has Windows and 1 has Linux? Serious, dude, you cannot give up to help me?

Comment: soandos: chkdsk works. I'm not sure but I think it says NTFS. I'm not sure about the chainloader but is this thing not starting the original Windows bootloader? So the original Windows bootloader must be somewhere?

Comment: @Chiyou, if `chkdsk` works, then the formatting for the drive is also good, and so what is the error with `bootsec`?

Comment: @soandos: It says Windows cannot detect the filesystem??

Comment: How are you running the command?

Comment: I boot into recovery console. Then I change the disk either C: or D: then I run chkdsk /F or /R.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4214/discussion-between-soandos-and-chiyou)